# How to download highways marked with a specific relation from OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, overpass-api

There's an excellent general question about downloading canals here: [How do I download specific OpenStreetMap data by tag?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18124/how-do-i-download-specific-openstreetmap-data-by-tag)

There's also plenty of knowledge about OSM in general, but one thing I always struggle with is downloading 'highways' marked as a specific relation. The cycle network, for example, consists of many types of features joined together with a single relation: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Cycle_routes

How could one, for example, download the entire [London Cycle Network](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_United_Kingdom_National_Cycle_Network/National_Routes) in a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Overpass turbo or the Overpass API, you get all national cycle routes that cross the Greater London border with

```
area["name"="Greater London"]->.boundaryarea;
(
relation(area.boundaryarea)[network=ncn];>;
);
out meta;
```

Don't try the same with larger areas, it will kill your browser.