# Is there a flag for osm osmosis to skip invalid nodes?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I am using osmosis to extract tags from an openstreetmap .bz2 file based on the command found in an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18124/downloading-specific-openstreetmap-data-by-tag)

```
bzcat us-west-latest.osm.bz2 | osmosis --rx - --log-progress --tf accept-ways man_made=wildlife_crossing  --tf reject-relations --used-node --wx - | bzip2 > just-wildlife-crossings.osm.bz2
```

this command works fine on other .bz2 osm files available on GeoFabrik, but is hanging on this one with the error:

```
Node 2925281281 does not have its lon attribute set; this attribute is required in current context.
```

I was looking at the [osmosis docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.44#Pipeline_Control) to see if there was a 'skip-errors' flag or something like that, but didn't see anything.

Is there a way to make osmosis push through invalid nodes?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of looking, it appears that osmosis is a legacy tool now with limited support. A newer tool, [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#introduction), completes this task and orders of magnitude faster than osmosis.

```
osmium tags-filter -o na-wildlife-crossings.osm north-america-latest.osm.pbf  nw/man_made=wildlife_crossing
```